# How do I define in a positive way my career goal to my boss, when I see that I'm failing?

Tags: career-development

My career progression since I joined to company is null or negative.

Next week I have to define my career goals with my boss.

However

- I just realized that the my project that soft-failed last year, is going to fail spectacularly this year
- New hires in my team make clear my gaps and weaknesses: I'm like the benchmarking for low performance in my team
- I don't see any space for me where I could thrive without being ridiculous
- In 3 years I didn't manage to get any visible task or responsibility: the only one that I pushed hard to get is the project I'm currently failing
- After funding cut, my boss applied the cut mostly to my projects

I would really to set my goal in a positive way, but I'm lost.

In reality, what I would like to set as a goal is:

- try not to be fired
- be able to explain professionally why my project fails, and why it will not be delivered
- try to be at the same level than other people in my team.

However I don't feel that such goals will be well received...I'd like to understand how to come out of this in a professional way

Answer (score 5):

You are setting very external goals. What I mean by that is that you can't control them or in some cases even influence them. Your project may fail because you aren't doing your job well, but it could also fail because of a change in the law or the business environment, or because it was never a good idea. Someone on your team could be better than you because you are not good at all, but they could also be better than literally everyone else in the company. If you don't reach these goals, you will be left with no idea why you didn't. You could get fired for reasons unrelated to the skills in which you are weak, or for a weakness you don't even know about.

Better goals are **about you**. They are largely **controlled by you**. You can work towards them rather than crossing your fingers and hoping someone gives them to you.

So, those skills you think you set a low benchmark for. Are they **important in your job** (not your team member's jobs)? For example, the UX person on a team needs to be great at building UX; do you? Do you need to know one or more programming languages well? Manage your time well? Estimate development effort? Find bugs? Make yourself a list of 10-15 things you should be good at in this job. It's possible "things the rest of the team is good at" will help to provide these items, but be aware you have your own sphere of skills and may be the only one bringing certain skills into the mix.

When you have the list, evaluate yourself (horrible, struggling, so-so, ok, brilliant) on each. Separately, write down how important you think each one is. Then find **at most three** that are important and that you need to improve on. Your goals are to improve at each of those things. You should also have a plan on how you will do that - take a course, read a book, ask someone who is good at them to pair with you once a week, whatever, the **work** of establishing **how to get better** at the things you are not good at is part of the work here.

Bring these goals to your boss. Your boss may not agree; they may think the things you want to improve aren't important or that improving something else is more important, but at least you have made a starting point. If you and your boss agree on three goals and the ways to work towards them, you'll be in a good position to get support (time and money) to do that work. If your boss gives you different goals, be sure to discuss what you will have to do to reach them.

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't think those goals would be well received at all. I don't know if your manager knows that your project is a surefire failure in your eyes, but I would definitely recommend telling them your concerns sooner rather than later. The earlier you ask for help, the better.

After that, it's time to regroup and shake it off. Coming out of this in a professional way is a combination of understanding your mistakes, planning how you are going to rectify them or learn and grow to avoid making them in the future, and setting goals for yourself to stay on track with that growth.

1. Take a step back and get an understanding of what went wrong with the project. You need to be able to explain to your manager why this project that you pushed for is going to end up failing.
2. Identify professional growth areas you can work on to be a better project lead in the future. You need to have a vision for what to improve so your manager can trust you in the future.
3. Set a plan for what that improvement looks like, with benchmarks and achievables. Are you taking courses? Getting coaching in a specific area from a colleague? Specifics are important. This step will help keep you accountable and let your manager know its something within your reach.

Comment: +1  If you are bad at something you need to be good at then plan how to get better.  In most jobs you do this by experience and education

Answer (score 1):

Career goals are about where you want to be in the future, not where you are now or even where you will be months from now. What do you want to do/achieve/be, what steps are you taking to get there, can you structure your job to help you get there, should you be taking additional classes in your own time. The way your current assignment impacts this is just that it may flag areas you want to work on to reach those longer term goals

Have one discussion at a time.

And note that goals and paths to/past them do change over time.

(I'm currently retired, and I still haven't really decided what I want to be when I grow up.)